# Keyboard disabled at Ubuntu 19.04 Login screen

Tags: keyboard, login, mouse, shutdown

I have trouble typing the password on the login screen. The keyboard is very slow and cannot type on the login screen, *only when the system is booting up from total shutdown*.

There is no problem if the system was on sleep mode and open back on. It only happens after the total shutdown. And they keyboard is totally fine in the system itself. The issue is only on the login screen.

So, I need to use on-screen keyboard and type the password with the mouse on the login screen after everytime I shut down my laptop. Would love to fix this issue to avoid typing password with the mouse. Please help :'(

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and Acer Vivobook15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem, except only after Sleep and Hibernates.  I know you said its only after booting from a total shutdown, but maybe this fix will work for you as well.
I had too much lag because too many features were enabled on the login screen.
Open Screensaver settings.  (I have a GUI for this but you might need to look up the command line command for this).  I disabled the "Allow keyboard shortcuts" and this made my login screen have much less lag and I could see my input key strokes as I typed them.  If that doesn't help, disable more of the settings.  (Again if you don't have a GUI for the screensaver settings, then you might have to look up the rest of the settings and command line commands for them).  Good luck!

Comment: Is it xscreensaver? I installed it and test out but no luck :'(

Comment: No I'm sorry its slick-greeter.  You might want to try installing the most simplest and fastest running greeter and see if that works (even if you don't want to use it) and then try more complex ones.

Comment: Well, my issue is solved after I switched to LightDM from gdm by installing unity-greeter. Seems like keyboard issue is from GDM. Thanks for sharing me to this greeters.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you figured it out